# system clock is 5.5 ahead although ntp

Tags: time, ntp

time zone here is Asia/Tehran,
but the ubuntu time is 5H30M ahead of local time.

I've checked configs and even installed ntp server, nothing seem to fix this,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

Current default time zone: 'Asia/Tehran'
Local time is now:      Thu May  9 00:49:38 IRDT 2013.
Universal Time is now:  Wed May  8 20:19:38 UTC 2013.
```

/etc/ntp.conf

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable


server ir.pool.ntp.org
server in.pool.ntp.org
server tr.pool.ntp.org

server ntp.ubuntu.com


restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
```

Here are current situation

```
$ date
    Sun May 12 17:15:39 IRDT 2013
$ date --utc
    Sun May 12 12:45:40 UTC 2013
according to Google my local time is 
    11:45 AM Sunday, May 12, 2013 (IRDT)
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with the output what time does your clock say, what time dose your computer say (via the date command) and what time does the internet say (from an NTP site)?

Comment: To get part of the info @coteyr wants, type `date` and then `date --utc`, put both outputs into your question along with the value you did expect.`

Comment: Trying to fix time with `$ ntpdate
12 May 17:21:49 ntpdate[4217]: no servers can be used, exiting `
while I can dig the time servers with no problem.